# Reducing/Folding a List of Strings to a Map[String,Boolean] in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a list like this:

`val objectKeys = List("Name","Place","Animal","Thing");`

I want to reduce it to a Map[String,Boolean] where Boolean is `element.size < 8`.

Here's what I wrote:

```
val mappedObject = objectKeys.fold(Map[String,Boolean])((map,key) => map + (key -> key.size < 8))
```

which gives me the following error:

```
value + is not a member of Object, but could be made available as an extension method.
```

and

```
value size is not a member of Object
```

My understanding about fold is that it takes a default argument and reduces the entire value around it which however doesn't seem to work in this case. Can anyone help me with this?

Ideally mappedObject should be like:

```
val mappedObject = Map[String,Boolean]("Name"->true,"Place"->true,"Animal"->true,"Thing"->true)
```

An equivalent Javascript implementation will be:

```
const listValues = ["Name","Place","Animal","Thing"];
const reducedObject = listValues.reduce((acc,curr) => {acc[curr] = curr.length < 8;
             return acc;
},{});
```

Comment: **Scala**, unlike **Javascript**, is a typed language. As such, you need to be careful of the types of the operations you perform. `fold` is unable to change the output type of the collection, since it doesn't provide any guarantees about the associativity order. - Whereas, `foldLeft` can change the output type since it knows the combine operation associates by the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it with a fold, that's easy to do:

```scala
objectKeys.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Boolean]) { (acc, key) =>
  acc + ((key, key.length < 8))
}
```

That said, I'm with Ivan on this one. `map` is clearly the better solution here (or `fproduct` if you're using the cats library).

Comment: will fold and foldLeft perform the same operation here? Why did you use `foldLeft` over `fold`?

Comment: The type signature of `fold` is `def fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1`. As you can see, it returns a value of type `A1`, and the `A1 >: A` bit tells us that `A1` must be a supertype of the list's elements' type `A`. That doesn't work out for us because we want to build a `Map[String, Boolean]`, and that is not a supertype of `String`.
`foldLeft`'s signature on the other hand is `def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B`. The type `B` is not constrained in any way, so this can indeed be used to build a `Map[String, Boolean]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case you should just `map` to a tuple containing your key with boolean check and then convert it to `Map[String, Boolean]` via `toMap` method as following.

```scala
objectKeys.map(key => (key, key.length < 8)).toMap
```

Comment: Hmm yeah I get this method but I was curious how can we do the same operation using fold or is it not possible that way?

Comment: it is possible but then you need to use an accumulator, add/modify it. And the code will be much longer also. `map` just fits well here. And `map` also looks similar to what `reduce` from javascript is doing

Comment: Yeah right makes sense, thanks @Ivan